# MiniProfiler.Current is null when called from System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler

Tags: asp.net-web-api, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm using mini profiler in my asp.net Web API project and want to track the performance of some code that runs in a custom DelegatingHandler.

The calls `MiniProfiler.Current.Step()` inside the `DelegatingHandler` don't show up in the results. Other calls in the same project show up ok.

Further investigation revealed that `MiniProfiler.Current` is retrieved from `HttpContext.Current` in the `WebRequestProfilerProvider`. And `HttpContext.Current` is null when called from  `DelegatingHandler`.

Is there a better way to retrieve the MiniProfiler.Current so that it works inside the handler?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question?

[Does MvcMiniProfiler require a web application to work, or can it be used in pure libraries, such as in unit tests?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526609/does-mvcminiprofiler-require-a-web-application-to-work-or-can-it-be-used-in-pur

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MiniProfiler Timings are stored in `HttpContext.Current` by default (as you discovered). Thus if you are calling MiniProfiler from a place where `HttpContxt.Current` is null, the results cannot be saved. The solution is to save (and retrieve) the results from somewhere else.

MiniProfiler offers the option of the option of changing the location where all results should be stored and retrieved from (using `MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage`). The [new v3 MiniProfiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/releases/tag/v3.0.10-beta) ([beta nuget here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler/3.0.10-beta4)) offers the option of configuring different `IStorage` for each request, and for using a `MultiStorageProvider` to designate multiple locations into which results can be stored and retrieved. You can see an example of this in the [Sample.Mvc](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/Sample.Mvc/Global.asax.cs#L120) project on github.

In your case, the best approach might be to set a `MultiStorageProvider` for your global `MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage` that will first save/retrieve from `HttpRuntimeCacheStorage` and then afterwards will use some other `IStorage` that is accessible from the `DelegatingHandler`. Then in the `DelegatingHandler`, set the `MiniProfiler.Current.Storage` to only use the second storage option that you set in the `MultiStorageProvider` (since it is pointless to try to save the the HttpCache). In this was, profiles from the `DelegatingHandler` will be saved into your second storage option, and will be retrieved for view with your other results (since `MultiStorageProvider` will [`Load`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/v3.0.10-beta/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/MultiStorageProvider.cs#L91) results from the first place it can get them - if it doesn't find the result in HttpCache, it will go to the second option.

Note - having multiple storage options is useful in this case, but it can have a negative impact on the performance of retrieving profiles.